# How to remove alert view button in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, swiftui, uialertcontroller

I have scenario where I need to display an alert without any button. Is it possible to remove the buttons from the default `Alert` in `SwiftUI`?

I know how to create a custom view as `Alert`. But I would love to use the default one instead of creating a custom one.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Alert") {
            showingAlert = true
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Important message"), message: Text("Wear sunscreen"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How would the user dismiss it then?

Comment: It's requirement. Is it possible to remove button ?

Comment: It can be done using `UIAlertController`.

Comment: In your case you should use an overlay.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `alert` view modifier cannot create alerts without any buttons. The descriptions of the initialisers for [`Alert`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/alert) are:

> Creates an alert with one button.

> Creates an alert with two buttons.

> Creates a side by side button alert.

All of these create alerts with buttons.

Note that `Alert` is deprecated since iOS 16.4. Now you should use one of the new `alert` modifiers like [this one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/alert(_:ispresented:actions:message:)-3rabc).

However, the new `alert` modifiers cannot create alerts without buttons either. All of their documentation mentions that:

> If no actions are present, the system includes a standard “OK” action.